# How to implement image belt with horizontal and vertical transition animations in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, swift, uikit

I'm new to the iOS UI development and I need some help to figure out, what is the best way to implement image belt (sequence of images in horizontal belt). I don't need details (someone to write me the code), just guidance what I should focus on learning as a libraries and most important design patterns (by design patters I mean software design for iOS UI).

The task details:
1. I will have image belt - sequence of few related images. This will be my horizontal transition. The transition animation will be simple push animation (something like push CATransion), initiated by swipe left/right. On top of the images there will be overlay with some text, icon info and etc. The overlay info will be the same for all images in the current belt.
2. I will have multiple image belts - this will be my vertical transition. The transition between belts will be triggered by swipe up/down. The different belts will contain unrelated information, so the information shown in overlays from point 1 must be also changed. The animation will be also simple push animation as in point 1.

I probably should inherit UIView and implement my belt as one object, which will consist of different UIView(overlay) and UIImageViews(for the images). Am I on the right track?

Some helpful brainstorm will be highly appreciated.

Comment: [Like This](http://imageshack.com/a/img910/1817/zkqVtJ.png) ?

Comment: It sounds to me like a collection view, UICollectionView, which is similar to a table but far more customizable. I think what you would want to do is have a vertical collection view of horizontal collection views. All the gesture recognizers would be built in. Speculation here, but I think it would work. Be aware that, like the UITableView, you will need to use delegation. So also look at UICollectionViewDelegate to see exactly what that does for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - I've done many of these. You add a UIView above the top view. I usually use a full-screen one with some alpha so they can see through the core content a little. Then add stuff on top of that which won't change: things like your text, icons, etc... Then on top of that you put the image you want to swipe and add a swipe gesture recognizer, typically one for left and one for right. When they swipe you init a new UIView off the edge of the device, init it with the image, and animate the frames of both left or right, depending on which way they've swiped. Mine are help tutorials showing how to use my app step-by-step so I also init multi-part animations on some of the frames that fly in; that's a nice looking optional effect. Here's the one I use (with the animation support stripped out or it'd be too much code) and there's lots of variations. Edited to note my app doesn't support rotation but if yours does you have to adjust the frames after a rotation.

```
    - (void)init
    {
        currentPanelNumber = 10;
    self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    if (self)
    {
        [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        currentPanelNumber = 10;

        overlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
        overlay.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.9 green:.9 blue:.9 alpha:.9];
        [self.view addSubview:overlay];

        CGRect currentPanelFrame = CGRectMake(267, 175, 494, 444);

        currentPanel =
            [[HelpView alloc] initWithFrame:currentPanelFrame withImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"10"]];
        currentPanel.frame = currentPanelFrame;
        [overlay addSubview:currentPanel];

        // ----------------------------------
        // Gesture swipes go here
        swipeLeftRecognizer =
            [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeLeft:)];
        [swipeLeftRecognizer setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
        [overlay addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeftRecognizer];

        swipeRightRecognizer =
            [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeRight:)];
        [swipeRightRecognizer setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
        [overlay addGestureRecognizer:swipeRightRecognizer];

        swipeDownRecognizer =
            [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeDown:)];
        [swipeDownRecognizer setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown];
        [overlay addGestureRecognizer:swipeDownRecognizer];

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer =
            [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
        [overlay addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];

        skipIcon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SkipAndStartIcon"]];
        CGSize size = CGSizeMake(84, 124);
        skipIcon.frame = CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width/2)-(size.width/2), self.view.frame.size.height-size.height-25, size.width, size.height);
        [self.view addSubview:skipIcon];
}

- (void)goNext
{
    // Clear out all subviews to remove lingering animations
    [[currentPanel subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];

    if(currentPanelNumber>=80)
    {
        [self closeHelp];
        return;
    }

    NSString *nextImage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", currentPanelNumber+10];

    CGRect nextPanelFrame = CGRectMake(765, 175, 494, 444);
    nextPanel = [[HelpView alloc] initWithFrame:nextPanelFrame withImage:[UIImage imageNamed:nextImage]];

    nextPanel.frame = nextPanelFrame;
    [overlay addSubview:nextPanel];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.2 animations:^
    {
        nextPanel.frame = currentPanel.frame;
    }
    completion:^(BOOL finished)
    {
        currentPanel.image = nextPanel.image;
        nextPanel.alpha = 0;
        currentPanelNumber += 10;
}

- (void)goPrevious
{
    if(currentPanelNumber<=10)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Clear out all subviews to remove lingering animations
    [[currentPanel subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];

    NSString *nextImage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", currentPanelNumber-10];

    CGRect nextPanelFrame = CGRectMake(-230, 175, 494, 444);

    // nextPanel = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:nextImage]];
    nextPanel = [[HelpView alloc] initWithFrame:nextPanelFrame withImage:[UIImage imageNamed:nextImage]];

    nextPanel.frame = nextPanelFrame;
    [overlay addSubview:nextPanel];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.2 animations:^
    {
        nextPanel.frame = currentPanel.frame;
    }
    completion:^(BOOL finished)
    {
        currentPanel.image = nextPanel.image;
        nextPanel.alpha = 0;
        currentPanelNumber -= 10;            
    }];
}
```